# If statement that is never called

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have this piece of code

```
Category featured = new Category()
            {
                active = true,
                Categories = new Category[0],
                description = "",
                identifier = "featured",
                name = "Featured",
                Products = new Product[0],
                url = siteUrl,
            };
StatisticCounters.CategoriesCounter();
```

then below this I have this code.

```
private IList<Category> FeatureSubCategories(HtmlNode std, Category category,Category featured)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    {
        if (category.name == "Featured")
        {
            var nodes = std.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'widget')] [position() <= 4]"); //TODO

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                string name = SiteParserUtilities.ParserUtilities.CleanText(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.InnerText));
                string url = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
                string identifier = url.Split('/').Last().Replace(".html", "");
                WriteQueue.write(string.Format(" Category [{0}].. {1} ", name, url));

                IList<Category> sub = GetSubCategories(std);
                Category c = new Category()
                {
                    active = true,
                    Categories = sub.ToArray(),
                    description = "",
                    identifier = identifier,
                    name = name,
                    Products = new Product[0],
                    url = url,
                };
                StatisticCounters.CategoriesCounter();
                categories.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    return categories;
}
```

for some reason tho when I run the code the if statement `if (category.name == "Featured")` is never called and I am not sure why this is. To start to parse the xpath and store them links into an array. Thank you for any help which you can give.

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and see what the value of `category` is?

Comment: Why do you think it's never called?

Comment: My advice would be removing the bracelets below the List declaration of _categories_. They don't make any sense to me, because you are ending your list declaration with a semicolon.

Comment: If I am honest I am not sure why its not called. The only thing I can think of that it doesn't no Category featured = new Category(). But I am not sure how I would get it to find it

Comment: It will be called, but evaluated to be false as it seems. you showed us, how the variable `featured` is filled, but you are checking `category.name` not `featured.name`. So `category.name` can very well be different from `"Featured"` and the body of the `if` statement will be skipped.

Comment: @Corak Yes, but it's a parameter. You can't know if he is referring to the first or the second parameter. Although i suspect you are right.

Comment: @Rob of course you're right. I connected the variable name to the parameter name which could be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

It is best to check in debugger. Some times whites spaces cause the problem. It is simple mistake done by many programmers. When we get data from database, there may be some leading spaces. When we compare with some value (thinking that there is no leading space), it will not compare without trimming those spaces. For example

```
string s1 = "TEST"; 
string s2 = " TEST"; 
if (s1 == s2) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Equal"); 
}
```

Please use trim function  to remove any white spaces and compare.